# Map JSON response from webservice into Angular class when there is space in JSON field Names

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a JSON structure like this

```
Data:[{'Project Name':'P1',PCode:1},{'Project Name':'P2',PCode:2},{'Project Name':'P1',PCode:3}]
```

But the trouble is when trying to map this JSON into angular class, how can I map without having any trouble with the space in field name

```
projects:project[]=[];
this.apiService.getTest().subscribe((data: any) => {
this.projects= data.Data;

 });

 export class project{
    projectCode:string;
    projectName:string;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a map:

```js
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

this.apiService.getTest().pipe(
  map((data: any) => {
    data.Data = data.Data.map((item: any) => ({
        projectName: item['Project Name'],
        projectCode: item.PCode
      });
    return data;
  })
).subscribe((data: any) => this.projects= data.Data);
```

In case you're using rxjs < v5.5.x

```js
import { map } from 'rxjs/operator/map';

this.apiService.getTest()
  .map((data: any) => {
    data.Data = data.Data.map((item: any) => ({
        projectName: item['Project Name'],
        projectCode: item.PCode
      });
    return data;
  }).subscribe((data: any) => this.projects= data.Data);
```

You can also look for some mapper on Google, but I think it's easier to manually map things as I did above.

Answer (score 1):

Use Array.prototype.map for this scenario. Please try like this

```
this.apiService.getTest().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.projects =  data.Data.map(item => {
         return {
              projectName: item['Project Name'],
              projectCode: item.PCode 
         }
      })

     });
```

Comment: Please do not post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: That's great to hear